# Can we spellcheck our tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, specific-tag

Today, I came across [software-recomendation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recomendation). No, I did not spell that wrong: the tag's creator did. 11 questions and apparently nobody's noticed yet: it should be [software-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations).

1. Can we rename that tag?
2. Let's just make sure our other tags haven't got a similar problem...

Comment: Good catch. I'll fix that one.

Comment: Also: [tag:super-nova] should really be [tag:supernova].

Comment: @HDE226868 Good catch too; I'll fix that one as well. Maybe we need to handle this question some other way...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Community wiki answer of tags that need to be fixed?

Comment: @HDE226868 Or a simple [tags] meta question (not [specific-tag]) with one answer per tag that people feel needs renaming? That way we get to keep [status-completed] here and can close this one off...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'll start that.

Comment: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/what-tags-need-renaming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag [software-recomendation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recomendation) has been renamed to [software-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations).

Based on HDE 226868's comment I also renamed [super-nova](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-nova) to [supernova](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supernova).

It may take a few moments for the changes to fully propagate throughout the system.