# What tags need renaming?

Tags: discussion, tags

In [Can we spellcheck our tags?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2118/can-we-spellcheck-our-tags), ArtOfCode brought up the fact that we had (note the past tense; Michael Kjörling took care of it) a [software-recomendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recomendations) tag when we really needed a [software-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) tag. I also noticed that we had (again, past tense) a [super-nova](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-nova) tag when we needed a [supernova](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supernova) tag.

Those are dealt with; chances are, others are not. Use an answer on this question to bring up a tag (one tag per answer, please!) you feel needs to be renamed, whether because of spelling or another reason.

Answer (score 3):

[weapon-mass-destruction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapon-mass-destruction) $\to$ [weapons-of-mass-destruction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons-of-mass-destruction)

The "of" is typically used in the phrase, and it makes the phrase grammatically correct. Also, pluralization would be nice.

Comment: I believe the actual tag is [tag:weapon-mass-destruction] (singular). The only question that uses the plural is the one you just asked.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Ack! My bad. I'll fix both.

Comment: Oh, well, the old one is fine now, but I think it should still be renamed to the plural, [tag:weapons-of-mass-destruction].

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Pluralization is a different request.

Comment: But they'd already be changing it, two changes to the same tag just seems redundant.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Implemented.

Comment: I think this is a great idea, but unfortunately tag names are limited to 25 characters. `weapons-of-mass-destruction` is too long.

Comment: mass-destruction-weapons would be grammatically correct and within the 25 character limit (24).  The variants with "of" are either 27 or 26 characters.  Of course, the "of" variants also include a cultural reference.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED, as requested:

I propose [software-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) loses the "recommendations" part?

I don't have a problem with [epidemiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epidemiology), but some people might not know this term; please consider changing it to "disease".

I see no purpose for the  [chemoautotrophism](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemoautotrophism) tag, and recommend removing it.

We have frequently-used [climate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate) and [weather](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather), so please consider removing the never-used [meteorology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteorology).

Comment: Can you make each suggestion its own answer? Thanks.

Comment: Sure!  Cheers for that.

Comment: I agree with all these suggestions.

Comment: Oh, I meant a separate *post* for each one, to make voting easier. :-)

Comment: chemoautotrophism was one I had to look up before answering [this question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/chemoautotrophic-flora)...but probably questions about non-solar based life could be better served by a more known word.

Comment: [tag:meteorology] is a synonym of [tag:weather] - as in if someone tries to use meteorology, it gets replaced with weather. No need to remove it

Comment: I think that removing recommendations from software-recommendations would be confusing and lead to people tagging virtual reality and such questions with software.  The other tags have either become synonyms or been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

[mines](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mines) $\to$ [mining](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining)

Perhaps this is just semantics, but "mining" encompasses the entire industry, not just the structures used in it.

Comment: As an added bonus, there will no longer be confusion when asking questions about explosive traps.

Answer (score 0):

Should we keep [xenobiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenobiology) or [exobiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exobiology) ?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenobiology#Difference_between_xeno-.2C_exo-.2C_and_astro-biology) says that they're different, but if we must lose one I vote we keep the former.